# Como agregar una fila a una tabla de Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Tengo una tabla en primefaces a la cual ya le agregue unas columnas,
ahora lo que quiero es agregar filas, y tengo lo siguiente pero solo muestra texto en las columnas y no muestra lo que tengo en los outputLabel, o de que manera se hace?

```
<p:dataTable style="max-width:1900px;max-height:750px;">
                        <p:column  headerText="RFC" >
                            <p:outputLabel value="RUMS907856"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="NOMBRE">
                            <p:outputLabel value="JUAN"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="CLAVE">
                             <p:outputLabel value="123"/>
                        </p:column>
                      <p:column  headerText="1" ></p:column>
                      <p:column headerText="2">
                      </p:column>
                      <p:column headerText="3">
                      </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

Asi es como se muestra
[image: solo muestra el texto de las columnas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te falta hacer es asociar tu tabla con el `Managed Bean` o  `Bean` lo haces usando la propiedad `var` para asociar esa variable a tu lista que tienes en el `value` pones la lista que trae tus datos.

Ahora para las columnas pones el `p:outputLabel` en la propiedad  `value` como vez uso la variable que declare arriba para entrar a la propiedad del objeto

```
<p:dataTable id="dt_proceso" emptyMessage="No hay procesos encontrados" 
var="proceso" value="#{consultasRecontratacionMB.listProcesos}"
rows="20" paginator="#{consultasRecontratacionMB.listProcesos.size()>20}" 
paginatorPosition="bottom"  style="width: 80%;">

  <p:column headerText="Codigo Proceso" width="5%">
  <p:outputLabel value="#{proceso.idProcesoRecontratacion}"/>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Año" width="5%">
   <p:outputLabel value="#{proceso.anio}"/>
   </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: excelente, gracias!

Comment: De nada espero que te sirva